# Python recursion didn't give correct result for "sum of left leaves"

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

I wrote a code for the leetcode problem "108. Sum of Left Leaves" using recursion. It didn't give me the expected result.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution(object):
    def sumOfLeftLeaves(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: int
        """
        if root is None:

            return 0

        ans = 0

        if root.left and not root.left.left and not root.left.right:

            ans += root.left.val


        self.sumOfLeftLeaves(root.left)
        self.sumOfLeftLeaves(root.right)

        return ans
```

When the input is 
[3,9,20,null,null,15,7]

I expected a 24 to be returned, but the code only gave me 9

Answer (score 0):

You aren't adding the results of the leaves below the root. You need this:

```
class Solution(object):
    def sumOfLeftLeaves(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: int
        """
        if root is None:

            return 0

        ans = 0

        if root.left and not root.left.left and not root.left.right:
            ans += root.left.val

        ans += self.sumOfLeftLeaves(root.left) + self.sumOfLeftLeaves(root.right)

        return ans
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Could you kindly explain "ans += self.sumOfLeftLeaves(root.left) + self.sumOfLeftLeaves(root.right)" ? I noticed it is not adding up .val, but isn't ans defined as sum of .vals?

Comment: If the current node is a left leaf, you need to make its value the answer `ans += root.left.val`

If not, you need to add up all the left leaves under the left and right nodes under it `ans += self.sumOfLeftLeaves(root.left) + self.sumOfLeftLeaves(root.right)`